# Go lang - idiomatic default fallbacks

Tags: go

I'm fairly new to go (about 9 months now full time using Go). However, I'm used to Python, typescript and PHP and I always find a short cut with these languages. However, I'm struggling to know what would be the most idiomatic way to achieve the following:

```golang
transit := gin.H{
    "rise": rs.Rise.String(),
    "set":  rs.Set.String(),
}

if rs.Rise.IsZero() {
    transit["rise"] = nil
}

if rs.Set.IsZero() {
    transit["set"] = nil
}
```

Essentially, I set a default struct, then if I need to change, I change ... but it just feels inefficient to me ... so I'm wondering if there are any tricks here that I could use?

I've chosen this specific real-world scenario, but I'm happy to have examples (rather than coding for me) ...

Comment: What does “inefficient” mean here?

Comment: @JimB I should correct this to “verbose”

Comment: Verboseness is a poor metric in many cases, the difficulty in writing code is not number of characters typed, it’s communicating intent to the next reader of the code. The solution below is no less verbose in the given case, and with more conditions it still requires the overhead of tracking multiple other abstractions. Unless there is a huge number of options to set, I would expect to see a simple series of conditionals to deal with this in most code.

Comment: Yeh totally, it's always a tussle between readability and cleverness, the languages I'm most used to (Python, javascript and typescript) always provide a certain level of cleverness in detriment to readability IMHO.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

This is not inefficient in terms of execution. It may be a bit verbose compared to other languages. There are ways to shorten such repetitive code using anonymous functions. This can help shorten a lengthy repetitive section as you have without sacrificing readability.

```
type StringZeroable interface {
   fmt.Stringer
   IsZero() bool
}

checkZero:=func(in StringZeroable) interface{} {
   if in.IsZero() {
     return nil
   }
   return in.String()
}

transit := gin.H{
    "rise": checkZero(rs.Rise),
    "set":  checkZero(rs.Set)
}
```